# Neo vim flutter flutter/bin/dart.bat exited with code: 64

Tags: flutter, dart, neovim, neovim-plugin

I'am new into configuring neo vim and i just cant get debugger to work. When i  run dap.continue() im getting this error flutter/bin/dart.bat exited with code: 64

Code for configuring flutter-tools

```
 require("flutter-tools").setup {
              
                flutter_path = 'C:/flutter/flutter/bin/dart.bat',
             
                ui = {border = "rounded", notification_style = "plugin"},
                outline = {open_cmd = "30vnew", auto_open = false},
                closing_tags = {
                    highlight = "Comment",
                    prefix = "// ",
                    enabled = true
                },
                debugger = {
                    enabled = true,
                    run_via_dap = true,
                    register_configurations = function(_)

                        require('dap.ext.vscode').load_launchjs(nil, {})

                        require("dap").adapters.dart = {
                            type = "executable",
                            command = vim.fn.stpath("data") ..
                                "C:/users/user/AppData/Local/nvim-data/mason/bin/dart-debug-adapter.cmd",
                            args = {"dart"}
                        }

                    end
                },
                dev_log = {enabled = false, open_cmd = "tabedit"},
                lsp = {
                    color = {
                        enabled = true,
                        background = false,
                        background_color = {r = 220, g = 223, b = 228},
                        foreground = false,
                        virtual_text = true,
                        virtual_text_str = "■"
                    },
                    settings = {
                        showTodos = true,
                        completeFunctionCalls = true,
                        renameFilesWithClasses = "prompt",
                        enableSnippets = true,
                        enableSdkFormatter = true,
                        analysisExcludedFolders = {".dart_tool"}
                    }
                }
            }
```